# Save uitextview contents as doc file

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I added image to uitextview using

```
UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 100, 50)];
imgView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"test.png"];

[Report addSubview:imgView];
```

where Report is uitextview

I want to save the image and all the text in this uitextfield as doc file like this application

http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/documents-to-go-office-suite/id317117961?mt=8#

any suggestion to do that

Answer (score 0):

First you have to decide what format to save the document in (e.g., html,) then you need to convert the text and the image into the format you chose.

Comment: I said in my question that I neeed it to be doc file

Comment: Microsoft has released the specification for doc format here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc313118.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If calling a web service is an option, then you could try [Docmosis](http://www.docmosis.com).  You could send your image and text and have it produce and deliver a doc.